# Why React app cannot connect to Local mongodb using Localhost while success in 127.0.0.1

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, backend

I am a starter of React. I am trying to connect React back-end app with local mongodb. I have imported MongoClient from mongodb. However, I cannot use app.get to get connect with local mongodb using following code:

```
app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req, res) => {
    try
    {
        const articleName = req.params.name;

        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true});
        const db = client.db('my-blog');

        const articleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName })
        res.status(200).json(articleInfo);

        client.close();
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({'msg': 'Error connecting to db', error});
    }
})
```

The error likes

```
{
    "msg": "Error connecting to db",
    "error": {
        "reason": {
            "type": "Unknown",
            "servers": {},
            "stale": false,
            "compatible": true,
            "heartbeatFrequencyMS": 10000,
            "localThresholdMS": 15
        }
    }
}
```

However, it works when I edit the client command likes

```
        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true});
```

What is the difference between using localhost and 127.0.0.1. Shouldn't these two same?
Thanks

I use Mongo 5.0.9

Comment: When we use localhost, it doesn't use TCP/IP. But this doesn't explains why it affects it. I also encountered similar error with mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb', { useNewUrlParser: true, 
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useCreateIndex: true,});
```

Try the above code.
in mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb
I think you have to specify the DB name as well.

Hope this will be helpful to you.